# "Blender Crashes when..." Questions

Tags: discussion

There are many, many questions, concerning a situation: *"Blender crashes when..."*

---

<sub>Just a few examples from the last 2 months...</sub>

<sup><sub>[Blender GPU compute render preview crash](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149241/blender-gpu-compute-render-preview-crash),
[Blender crashes when entering viewport rendered mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200383/blender-crashes-when-entering-viewport-rendered-mode),
[Blender crashes several times and lags](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193379/blender-crashes-several-times-and-lags),
[Blender crashes when entering rendered view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148686/blender-crashes-when-entering-rendered-view),
[Blender crashes with GPU installed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116235/blender-crashes-with-gpu-installed),
[Windows 10 crashes using blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200119/windows-10-crashes-using-blender),
[How can I avoid crash when adding subdivision modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199667/how-can-i-avoid-crash-when-adding-subdivision-modifier),
[Blender render extremely slow on Linux (+ crashes)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197044/blender-render-extremely-slow-on-linux-crashes),
[Ubuntu. Blender crashes when opens Shader Editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196974/ubuntu-blender-crashes-when-opens-shader-editor),
[Always crash when I enter the rendered view in blender 2.90](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196921/always-crash-when-i-enter-the-rendered-view-in-blender-2-90),
[Crashing during particle bake (not from memory)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196407/crashing-during-particle-bake-not-from-memory),
[Blender crashing when using material preview or using eevee on Pop os 20.04](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196294/blender-crashing-when-using-material-preview-or-using-eevee-on-pop-os-20-04),
[Blender crashes when using any kind of normal map](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195754/blender-crashes-when-using-any-kind-of-normal-map),
[Blender won't see my nVidia GPU and 2.90 crashes but 2.91 doesn't](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195287/blender-wont-see-my-nvidia-gpu-and-2-90-crashes-but-2-91-doesnt),
[Cycles rendering mode crashes the entire program AMD OpenCL](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195383/cycles-rendering-mode-crashes-the-entire-program-amd-opencl),
[Blender crashes when rendering cycles although using good settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195232/blender-crashes-when-rendering-cycles-although-using-good-settings),
[Blender crashes when rendering cycles although using good settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195232/blender-crashes-when-rendering-cycles-although-using-good-settings),
[Import STL crashes Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195193/import-stl-crashes-blender)
[Blender 2.9 instantly crashes when I try to render in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195164/blender-2-9-instantly-crashes-when-i-try-to-render-in-cycles)
[Rendering (CPU+GPU) crash almost every time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194937/rendering-cpugpu-crash-almost-every-time)
[Blender Crashes When I Open A File](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194915/blender-crashes-when-i-open-a-file),
[Blender crashes when I use volume absorption](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194803/blender-crashes-when-i-use-volume-absorption),
[Normal maps baking crashes blender 2.90. Exact same blender file as in blender 2.83 where bake doesn't crash](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194445/normal-maps-baking-crashes-blender-2-90-exact-same-blender-file-as-in-blender-2),
[Exception Access Violation error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194315/exception-access-violation-error),
[Blender crashes after rendering one frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193699/blender-crashes-after-rendering-one-frame),
[Cycles crashing on gpu compute (RX 5700 with XT bios)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193525/cycles-crashing-on-gpu-compute-rx-5700-with-xt-bios/)</sub></sup>

---

Most don't have any answers, since the possible reasons are hard to pinpoint through Q&A format.

Should we have **one dedicated Q&A post** with possible reasons listed, for users to try?
Like:

- Update your GPU drivers
- Check if your HW meets the requirements
- Make sure your HW can handle the scene
- Try a different version
- Pray to Blender Gods... :)
- and so on...

Why it's a good idea:

1. It will be faster and more helpful for those asking for help <sup>(that's the point here, right?)</sup>
2. It will help protect our moderators' sanity :)
3. It will save time so people can focus on answering other questions

### What do you think?

Comment: The issue I have with crash related questions is that most often are off topic here. It is either a hardware problem, an issue with drivers, operating system, or just general poor computer health; all of which are unrelated and off topic here. Some times it is actually caused by a bug, but questions are so sparse in info that I'm reticent to send people to the bugtracker for fear of just burdening the developers even more. For graphics cards related issues it is probably a good idea to have a canonical answer covering usual steps, like checking for hardware compatibility, updating drivers etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of issues that users commonly ask about:

1. Operating system crashes while using Blender
2. Blender crashes or glitches

The former is off-topic, since it's unrelated to Blender. The actual issue is with the drivers, hardware or operating system. While Blender may trigger the exact circumstances that makes the system crash, a user space application shouldn't be able to. Therefore, this is not something we can help with on Blender's Stack Exchange nor on the official bug tracker.

A question about the latter might be on-topic, if it is about finding a workaround for a suspected bug that could be relevant to other users. Other types of questions will likely be off-topic, however that doesn't automatically mean that it's a bug and should be reported on the bug tracker. In order to help rule out common causes of issues and to improve the report quality from users that we redirect to the bug tracker, I've written a [little guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports/173685#173685). If users follow it, then they should either be able to resolve the issue themselves or have a well written bug report at the end, that allows developers to identify the source of the issue.

Comment: Oh, that's exactly what I had in mind :). Should I then flag those *"Blender crash..."* questions as duplicates of this *Bug report* Q&A? I'm just looking for the most 'helping' way to handle these situations :).

Comment: @JachymMichal I'd say ask questions in the comments first to check if the user has considered/checked likely causes, if it isn't clear from the question. If I think that it could be a bug, I would leave a comment and recommend them to go through the guide linked above and report it on the bug tracker. Next I'd vote to close the question using *a community-specific reason* and choose the option that says it should be reported on the bug tracker.

Comment: Okay, and if the user doesn't react, or it isn't reportable as a bug? What's the best action then? Because *that is* the case in most of the aforementioned questions :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Right, in that case it would still be off-topic and I think it should be closed using *a community-specific reason > Other - Add comment*, where you give a (very) short explanation why it's off-topic. For instance you could write: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a crashing operating system. Blender is not the source of the issue, this may be caused by an error in the graphics driver, operating system or hardware."

Comment: @JachymMichal on side note, when closing a question as Closing > A community specific reason > Bug it already links to [the guide by robert](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377)

Comment: @Duarte Yeah I noticed just yesterday when going through review queue :).

Comment: @Robert Yes, that's what I was going to do :). When I voted to [close this old one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/194315/78972) I added a link to your little guide so the OP knows what to do next :). Okay like this?

Comment: @JachymMichal Yes, I think so.

Comment: Great, thanks for your time :)